# Unbind events from all namespaces except a particular one

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

If I bind a jQuery `scroll` event handler to a particular namespace…

```
$(window).on('scroll._my_namespace',function() { ... });
```

…is there any way to then unbind all `scroll` event handlers *except* the ones assigned to that namespace? For example, if I do…

```
$(window).off('scroll._my_namespace');
```

…it would unbind that specific `scroll` handler, and if I do…

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

…it would unbind *all* `scroll` handlers.

**What I've tried so far:**

```
$(window).off('scroll.'); // Doesn't seem to do anything
```

Never expected this to work, but figured I'd better try it before posting:

```
$(window).off('scroll:not("._my_namespace")'); // Also doesn't do anything
```

#### What I want to do is unbind all `scroll` event handlers *except* the one assigned to a specific namespace. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any way using the public apis other than to have another common namespace for all the handlers that has to be removed.

But using the private events collection you can try something like

```
var events = $._data(window, 'events');
for (var i = events.scroll.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var handler = events.scroll[i];
    if (handler && handler.namespace != 'ns') {
        $(window).off('scroll', handler.handler)
    }
}
```

```js
$(window).on('scroll.ns', function(e) {
  console.log('x', e.type, e.handleObj.namespace, e)
});
$(window).on('scroll.ns2', function(e) {
  console.log('y', e.type, e.handleObj.namespace, e)
});
$(window).on('scroll.t', function(e) {
  console.log('z', e.type, e.handleObj.namespace, e)
});

$('button').click(function() {
  var events = $._data(window, 'events');
  for (var i = events.scroll.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var handler = events.scroll[i];
    if (handler && handler.namespace != 'ns') {
      $(window).off('scroll', handler.handler)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your namespaces and call `off` for each of them but he one you don't want.